# google openid error:The server could not process your request

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am interest to create openid application in django for that ,i had using django-auth-openid it is working fine in django development server but after i want deploy on production server using apache2, mod_wsgi. it is also working for yahoo correctly not working for google,it doesn't show the login page ,it shows "The server could not process your request" what is the problem ifallow the below link for apache and mod_wsgi configuration
http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/12/11/installing-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-10-04/